# How to install OS in VirtualBox in non-Windows drives

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

I have only 5GB disk space in C:\ which corresponds to my Windows drive. I am trying to install VirtualBox to enjoy the Fedora Linux OS. My requirement is that, I wish to install the fedora linux other than C:. Is it really possible in VirtualBox? Because when I tried, it got installed in C:\

Please suggest me the possible ways to install multiple OS on top of VirtualBox to be installed in non-windows drives (other than C:)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

By default, VirtualBox will create new machine definitions and their associated storage files in your %USERPROFILE% directory (it used to be in the .VirtualBox folder prior to the 4.x releases). You can however put the files anywhere you like. Here are two ways:

Under Preferences, General you can set the **Default Machine Folder** to be something other than C:\ (mine is currently set to E:\VirtualBox\Machines). This will be the new default for any machines (and storage) created after modifying this setting.

When you are creating a new virtual disk using the **New Virtual Disk Wizard**, it will prompt you for a name/location and size for the drive. Just prefix the name with the full path of where you want it stored (or click the little folder icon with a green up-arrow to navigate to your desired destination) and click next. You storage will be wherever you chose to put it.

Comment: Awesome - old post but it helped me out!